# Delay NSNotification until another is complete

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

I have a global function that downloads JSON data from a server and parses it. It normally takes about 5 seconds to run, so we do this in the background and then send out a notification, `kNotificationDownloadSuccessful`.

One of the several observers of the notification is a MapView, who re-draws annotations based on the data it received. This, obviously, has to happen after it's told the data is ready by receiving `kNotificationDownloadSuccessful`.

In *some* cases I want to re-center the map on the new data. This, obviously, cannot happen until the map has completed drawing annotations. So I implemented a second notification, `kNotificationMapLocationSet`, which the callers fire if they want this to occur, and the map listens for it.

Now the problem... `kNotificationMapLocationSet` is being received before `kNotificationDownloadSuccessful`, which makes perfect sense really. The Map can't simply re-post it, or just call it's local re-center method, because it doesn't know if the recenter is required.

I thought about having the `kNotificationMapLocationSet` set a flag in the Map, and then have the handler on `kNotificationDownloadSuccessful` look at it and recenter if desired. But then that would fail in the case where the messages *are* received in their current order.

So is there a way to order the notifications? IE, delay this one until that one fires?

Comment: You could let those who sent out `kNotificationMapLocationSet` listen for `kNotificationDownloadSuccessful` and then fire `kNotificationMapLocationSet` if it is necessary.

Comment: I think I see what you mean here... so trap downloadSuccess in both places and then fire the LocationSet, right? That does indeed sound like a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use addObserver to check when the NSNotification is done. Let me know if this works:

```
NotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(callNextNotification:) name:@"notificationSent" object:nil];
```

It looks like you subclassed NSNotification, but this should still work.